# Custom css not working after changing theme name?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have installed  **[Shopkeeper](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/shopkeeper-ecommerce-wp-theme-for-woocommerce/full_screen_preview/9553045)**  wordpress theme , in page source theme name was show like `wp-content/themes/shopkeeper` . I followed some steps to change theme name.

1) change theme folder name

2) in style.css change theme name and active it

Now Everything work fine theme name changed on page source but custom css is not working after changing theme name. is there any additional steps or plugin to change theme name properly .

Comment: Why the need to change the name to begin with? Only reason I could think of spontaneously would be that you might not be using a legally bought version of this theme … in which case please don’t expect support here for that in the first place.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the theme from updates?

Comment: yes no need to update